# LogicException: Host can not be empty

Tags: php, laravel, mailgun

Working with Laravel 6, PHP 7.4, and Mailgun. I am testing routes with Mailgun and when trying to create a client and show my routes I receive this error: LogicException - Host can not be empty.

I here is the snippit for creating the client

```
# Instantiate the client.
$mgClient = Mailgun::create('PRIVATE_API_KEY', 'https://API_HOSTNAME');

# Issue the call to the client.
$result = $mgClient->routes()->index();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$mgClient = Mailgun::create('PRIVATE_API_KEY', 'https://'.API_HOSTNAME);
```

And make sure you constant *API_HOSTNAME* is not empty.

Comment: Yes, I in my actual code my API Key and Hostname are there

Comment: yes but you need to change this line too.    
**FROM**    
`$mgClient = Mailgun::create('PRIVATE_API_KEY', 'https://API_HOSTNAME');`   
**TO**    
`$mgClient = Mailgun::create('PRIVATE_API_KEY', 'https://'.API_HOSTNAME);`